# Combine consecutive elements in a parent div

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a piece of code I use to load messages from a chat. Nothing special here, just check who sent the message and set the HTML class to be displayed accordingly. My real struggle is if you take a look at the picture below.

```
messages.forEach(message => {
 let div = document.createElement("div");
 let innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
 let innerInnerDiv = document.createElement("div");

 // if other user sent us message
 if (message.data().from === userId || message.data().to === user.displayName) {
   innerDiv.setAttribute("class", "first-message-div");
   innerInnerDiv.setAttribute("class", "firstmessages--main-div");

   div.setAttribute("class", "messagee");
   div.textContent = message.data().message;

   innerInnerDiv.appendChild(div);
   innerDiv.appendChild(innerInnerDiv);

 // if we sent message
 } else {

   innerDiv.setAttribute("class", "first-message-right");
   innerInnerDiv.setAttribute("class", "firstmessages--main-div");

   div.setAttribute("class", "messagee messagee-right");
   div.textContent = message.data().message;

   innerInnerDiv.appendChild(div);
   innerDiv.appendChild(innerInnerDiv);
 }

 chatSellerConversationMainDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
});
```

You can see messages loaded to the console

[image]

where divs with class `first-message-right` are messages sent by me, and divs with class `first-message-div` are sent by the other user.

And here you can see what is inside the div
[image]

My question how would it be possible to check if user sent multiple messages in a row, and combine those div messages inside a parent, either `first-message-right` or `first-message-div`.

For example to look something like this, if other user sent user a message and we replied with 3 messages.

```
class="first-message-div"
   class="firstmessages--main-div"
      class="messagee"
         Hi 


                                                              class="first-message-right" (Combines divs if consecutive messages from one user)
                                                                   class="firstmessages--main-div"
                                                                      class="messagee messagee-right"
                                                                         Hey there 
                                                                   class="firstmessages--main-div"
                                                                      class="messagee messagee-right"
                                                                         Hiiii 
                                                                   class="firstmessages--main-div"
                                                                      class="messagee messagee-right"
                                                                         Whats up 
class="first-message-div"
   class="firstmessages--main-div"
      class="messagee"
         Ok
```

I do not know how to approach this and where to begin. Hopefully someone could provide an insight how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` calls your function with a second argument, `index`. You can use that to look back at the previous message and then decide to re-use the previous `<div>` if it's from the same user.

```js
messages.forEach((message, index) => {
 // ...previous code...
 if (index > 0 && messages[index].data().from == message.data().from) {
   chatSellerConversationMainDiv.lastChild.appendChild(innerInnerDiv);
 } else {
   chatSellerConversationMainDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
 }
});
```